# Bootstrap Select (Silvio Moreto) selected text display

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select

Is there a way to change '2 items selected' to '2 crew selected'

in bootstrap-select.js there is the following:

```
<script>

Selectpicker.DEFAULTS = {
noneSelectedText: 'Special Invite',
noneResultsText: 'No results matched {0}',
countSelectedText: function (numSelected, numTotal) {
  return (numSelected == 1) ? "{0} crew selected" : "{0}  crew selected";
}


(function ($) {
$.fn.selectpicker.defaults = {
noneSelectedText: 'Special Invite',
noneResultsText: 'No results match {0}',
countSelectedText: function (numSelected, numTotal) {
  return (numSelected == 1) ? "{0} crew selected" : "{0} crew selected";
},
maxOptionsText: function (numAll, numGroup) {
  return [
    (numAll == 1) ? 'Limit reached ({n} item max)' : 'Limit reached ({n} items max)',
    (numGroup == 1) ? 'Group limit reached ({n} item max)' : 'Group limit reached ({n} items max)'
  ];
},
selectAllText: 'Select All',
deselectAllText: 'Deselect All',
multipleSeparator: ', '
};
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Two questions:

1) I'm getting an unexpected token ; after the (jQuery);

2) If I put these in a script tag will it overwrite the bootstrap version?

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to delete

```
Selectpicker.DEFAULTS = {
noneSelectedText: 'Special Invite',
noneResultsText: 'No results matched {0}',
countSelectedText: function (numSelected, numTotal) {
return (numSelected == 1) ? "{0} crew selected" : "{0}  crew selected";
}
```

and the script works.